# Java: How to create new class object for Reader class from java.io when it has protected constructor

Tags: java, class, constructor, protected

I wanted to create a new class object for java's Reader class, but I can't access the constructor since it is protected.

[Reader Class Description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html)

```
Reader myReader = new Reader();
```

Will not work.

Normally, I would create a new function that class to access that constructor, but since the function is a part of java default library, how do I access it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Here's a question for you.  What do you expect a (hypothetical) instance of the Reader class would actually do when you call `read()`?  Where would it get the character from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reader is an abstract class. You cannot instantiate it, only for the purposes of making a subclass instance.

Did you mean

```
Reader myReader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: And what is "in" in this example?

Comment: `in` is the InputStream that the InputStreamReader should read from.

Comment: I have this `BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));` and It gives error "cannot find symbol `in`" when I run this.

Comment: Here `in` was undefined so It is solved by importing `import static java.lang.System.in`, which does the job.

Answer (score 4):

[`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) is an abstract class, so you must instantiate an implementation of it, such as [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) or [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html).

Answer (score 3):

As others said, you may create a instance of subclass of `Reader`, such as `BufferedReader`.

If you don't want to use subclass of Reader, you may create instance of `Reader` like below

```
Reader reader = new Reader() {

        @Override
        public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }};
```

Comment: +1 for demonstrating that subclasses (which this one is, anonymous as it may be) *can* call that protected constructor.

Comment: @Thilo thanks for the comment. Yes, it creates an anonymous subclass instance in fact. Of course, a subclass instance is a superclass instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [Reader Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) you can see the concrete subclasses of `Reader` intialyze any one of them based on your requirement. You cannnot instantial `Reader` as it is `abstract`

BufferedReader
CharArrayReader
FilterReader
InputStreamReader
PipedReader
StringReader